# Assembly Indexed Mode

Tags: assembly, msp430, addressing-mode

Here's the assignment:

> Write a program in assembly such that it contains a subroutine which performs the AND operation with the entry of register `R6` and hexadecimal #0001h. And then repeat it by applying the same operation to five successive memory locations. Use an appropriate addressing mode.

For the first part, I just did `and.w #0001h, R6`. For the second part, I was hinted to use indexed mode and to use this format:

```
Loop
mov.w (0)R4, R6
call and_subroutine
add 2, R4
jmp Loop
```

And use `cmp` to exit out of this loop. Before I can figure out how to do the rest of the problem, I wanted to test out bits and I entered:

```
mov.w #0200h, R4
mov.w (0)R4, R6
and.w #0001h, R6
mov.w (2)R4, R6
```

For the `(0)R4` and `(2)R4` lines, it gives me this error:

> Unexpected trailing operand(s)

I tried taking out the last 2 lines trying with just `(0)R4`, but that didn't help the error. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which assembler are you using? TI or GNU?

Comment: Figured it out, but thank you!